# LWC Cards carousel

Tags: lightning-web-components, carousel

I need to implement carousel of cards in lwc using left and right arrows, similar to the home Page in Salesforce (shown below). Is there any out of box lwc component available for the same. I tried using lightning-carousel but seems that is for only images with one screen at a time. Any leads will help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only `lightning-carousel-image` can be used inside `lightning-carousel` and text is not supported as of now.

**If you need to use components other than images, then you will need to create the custom one. You can refer to the [SLDS Carousel docs](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/carousel/#Keyboard-Interactions) for that.**

[Documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel/example)

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-size_3-of-4">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">Carousel With disable-auto-scroll Attribute
        <lightning-carousel disable-auto-scroll>
            <lightning-carousel-image
                src = "https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-01.jpg"
                header = "First Card"
                description = "First card description."
                alternative-text = "First card accessible description."
                href = "https://www.salesforce.com">
            </lightning-carousel-image>
            <lightning-carousel-image
                src = "https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-02.jpg"
                header = "Second Card"
                description = "Second card description."
                alternative-text = "Second card accessible description."
                href = "https://www.salesforce.com">
            </lightning-carousel-image>
            <lightning-carousel-image
                src = "https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-03.jpg"
                header = "Third Card"
                description = "Third card description."
                alternative-text = "Third card accessible description."
                href = "https://www.salesforce.com">
            </lightning-carousel-image>
        </lightning-carousel>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't want image. For me the content are cards/tiles . Also i want  four of the cards visible at a time.

Comment: Aah!! I guess only `lightning-carousel-image` is supported.

Answer (score -2):

////////////JS//////////////

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import cssFile from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myCardCSS';

export default class carousel extends LightningElement {

    cards = [
        {
            id: '1',
            title: 'Card 1',
            icon: 'standard:account',
            content: 'This is the content for card 1.'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'Card 2',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 2.'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            title: 'Card 3',
            icon: 'standard:lead',
            content: 'This is the content for card 3.'
        },
        {
            id: '4',
            title: 'Card 4',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 4.'
        },
        {
            id: '5',
            title: 'Card 5',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 5.'
        },
        {
            id: '6',
            title: 'Card 6',
            icon: 'standard:account',
            content: 'This is the content for card 6.'
        },
        {
            id: '7',
            title: 'Card 7',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 7.'
        },
        {
            id: '8',
            title: 'Card 8',
            icon: 'standard:lead',
            content: 'This is the content for card 8.'
        },
        {
            id: '9',
            title: 'Card 9',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 9.'
        },
        {
            id: '10',
            title: 'Card 10',
            icon: 'standard:contact',
            content: 'This is the content for card 10.'
        }
    ];

    activeIndex = 0;

    handlePreviousBtn() {
        if (this.activeIndex > 0) {
            this.activeIndex--;
        }
    }

    handleNextBtn() {
        if (this.activeIndex < this.cards.length - 4) {
            this.activeIndex++;
        }
    }

    get cardsToShow() {
        return this.cards.slice(this.activeIndex, this.activeIndex + 4);
    }

    renderedCallback(){
        loadStyle(this, cssFile);
    }
}
```

///////////////////css/////////////////////

```
.slds-carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* margin-top: 1rem; */
}

.slds-carousel__stage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slds-carousel__panels {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slds-carousel__panel {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.slds-carousel__controls {
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 90%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /* width: 100%; */
    left: 90%;
    height: 40px;
}

.slds-button {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.slds-button_icon-x-small {
    padding: 0;
}

.slds-button_icon-border-filled {
    border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
    background-color: #f3f4f5;
    color: #1b1f23;
}

.slds-button_icon-border-filled:hover {
    background-color: #d8dde6;
    color: #1b1f23;
}

.slds-text-color_default {
    color: #1b1f23;
}
```

--------------LWC--------------

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-carousel">
        <div class="slds-carousel__stage">
            <div class="slds-carousel__panels">
                <template for:each={cardsToShow} for:item="card">
                    <div key={card.id} class="slds-carousel__panel">
                        <lightning-card class="my-card" title={card.title} icon-name={card.icon}>
                            <p>{card.content}</p>
                        </lightning-card>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-carousel__controls">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small slds-text-color_default" title="Previous" onclick={handlePreviousBtn}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevronleft" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
            </button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small slds-text-color_default" title="Next" onclick={handleNextBtn}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevronright" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Code dumps make poor answers. The explanation is as important as the solution.